# React Testing Library: When to use userEvent.click and when to use fireEvent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm presently learning React-Testing-Library.

I'd like to test mouse interaction with an element. Presently it's a bit unclear to me the difference between userEvent.click(element) and fireEvent.click(element). Are both recommended for use, and in the example below are they being correctly implemented?

```
const mockFunction = jest.fn(() => console.info('button clicked'));
const { getByTestId } = render(<MyAwesomeButton onClick={mockFunction} />);
const myAwesomeButton = getByTestId('my-awesome-button');

// Solution A
fireEvent(myAwesomeButton)
expect(mockFunction.toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

// Solution B
userEvent.click(myAwesomeButton);
expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Thanks in advance for any clarity.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Behind the scenes, `userEvent` uses the `fireEvent`. You can consider `fireEvent` being the low-level api, while `userEvent` sets a flow of actions.

[Here is the code for `userEvent.click`](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/blob/5feaa942f46bb37d96c2f2fbeb4b33e8beff75ad/src/click.js#L87-L103)

You can see that depending of which element you are trying to click, `userEvent` will do a set of different actions (e.g. if it's a label or a checkbox).

Comment: a good example is when you fire a click event on a button with fireEvent.click, the button will not be focused. The button is not focused. 
But with userEvent.click(), this button will be focused. useEvent can better reflect users' real behaviour.

Answer (score 25):

According to [Docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro#difference-to-fireevent), you should use `user-event` to test interaction with your components.

`fireEvent` dispatches exactly the events you tell it to and just those - even if those exact events never had been dispatched in a real interaction in a browser.

`User-event` on the other hand dispatches the events like they would happen if a user interacted with the document. That might lead to the same events you previously dispatched per `fireEvent` directly, but it also might catch bugs that make it impossible for a user to trigger said events.

Answer (score 5):

another good to mention difference between `fireEvent` and `userEvent` is that
by default fireEvent is wrapped inside `act` function and this is useful when the user does some action and this action will cause component updates and re-render. On the contrary, if we used `userEvent` probably will notice `"not wrapped in act(...)" warning` error that appears in the console.

```
act(() => {
  userEvent.type(input, 'inputValue')
})
```

and here we don't need the act function, cause it's already wrapped over fireEvent

```
fireEvent.change(input, {target: {value: 'inputValue'}})
```

and this great article demonstrates this concept
[Common mistakes with React Testing Library](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library)

Comment: Above answer said userEvent uses the fireEvent - wouldn't that imply it also already has act if fireEvent is wrapped?

Comment: userEvent is already wrapped in act. You are probably seeing the acr(...) warning, because userEvent is async and you should await it.

Comment: i agree with @Mister_CK, this advice is wrong, you forgot to await the `useEvent.type()`.

Answer (score 3):

I want to build upon the accepted [answer from @Guilhermevrs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64008376/3673659). There has been one change since, and that is that `userEvent` doesn't use `fireEvent` from v14 on, but this doesn't affect `userEvent.click()` directly.

---

To mimic user interactions like clicking buttons or inputting text for testing, the Testing Library provides various APIs. These APIs are:

- **[`fireEvent`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events)**: This synchronous, low-level API works as a wrapper around the [`dispatchEvent` Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent). For example, you can trigger a `click` event on a button using `fireEvent.click(buttonElement)` which would trigger an `onClick`handler function on the component.
- **[`userEvent`](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event)**: An asynchronous, high-level API, `userEvent` simulates real user behaviour by triggering multiple events within a single interaction. The `userEvent` offers two primary methods to simulate keyboard and pointer interactions, along with utility methods expanding on these.

  - **[`userEvent.keyboard()`](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/keyboard)**: This method replicates events like `keyDown` and `keyUp` using the [`dispatchEvent` Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).
  - **[`userEvent.pointer()`](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/pointer)**: Similar to `userEvent.keyboard()`, this method triggers a variety of pointer events using the `dispatchEvent` Web API. For example, `userEvent.pointer({ keys: '[MouseLeft]', target: buttonElement})` triggers the `pointerDown`, `mouseDown`, `pointerUp`, `mouseUp` and `click` event.
  - **Utility methods**: These methods combine the previous two methods to closely simulate real user behavior.

    - [`userEvent.type()`](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/utility#type): This method emulates a `click`, `keydown`, `keyup` and `input` event. Hence, `userEvent.type(inputElement, 'hello')` triggers `onClick`, `onKeyDown`, `onKeyPress`, `onKeyUp`, and `onChange` handlers on the component.
    - [`userEvent.click()`](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/convenience#click): This method emulates a `hover` and `click` event. For instance, `userEvent.click(buttonElement)` activates all the events from `userEvent.pointer` with `mouseEnter`, `pointerEnter`, `mouseOver` and `pointerOver`, but no `mouseLeave` and `pointerLeave` since the pointer will stay on the element.
    - ... you can find the others on the [Utility](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/utility) and [Convenience](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/convenience) pages

> Before version 14, `userEvent` internally used `fireEvent`. There was, however, a need for `userEvent` to have more control over the changes happening to the DOM. As a result, the internal calls to `fireEvent` have been removed in the later versions and `userEvent.keyboard` and `userEvent.pointer` themselves now expand on the [`dispatchEvent` Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

While `userEvent` is usually the preferred option because of its high-level abstraction and realism, you can fallback on `fireEvent` if you need to mimic edge case interactions that `userEvent` doesn't support.

> **`userEvent` limitations**
> To name a few limitations of `userEvent`:
>
> - it does not yet fully support keyboard composition sessions ([#1097](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/1097)), which is the ability to simulate a user typing in text through the keyboard in a specific manner.
> - it inaccurately handles events in number input fields, where pressing ArrowUp/ArrowDown does not trigger an onChange event ([#1066](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/1066)).
> - it falls short in simulating the interaction with `datalist` elements ([#1088](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/1088)).
>
> These limitations are not typically encountered in daily use cases. To circumvent these issues, consider using the `keyboard` or `pointer` modules. Alternatively, the lower-level API `fireEvent` can be used.

It should also be noted that using `userEvent` trades performance for accuracy. You remove risks of incorrect assumptions in your test - such as an why `onKeyDown` event not being triggered - when a seemingly simple thing like typing into a textbox is performed. But hence, `userEvent` [can be 10x slower than a single `fireEvent`](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/discussions/977).