# How to test this component staying aligned with React Testing Library Principles?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am testing a component and wondering what the best approach would be that would test the component *without* testing implementation details.

The component renders conditionally based on the `width` and `isDropdown` state, but not sure how to test how the DOM would look by changing these values or even if that would be the correct approach.

Here is the component:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import useWindowDimension from '../../hooks/useWindowDimensions'
import { QueryType } from '../../constants'

type choiceProps = {
    type: QueryType
    isChosen: boolean
    setFeedChoice: (query: QueryType) => void
}

const FeedChoice = ({ type, isChosen, setFeedChoice }: choiceProps) => {
    return (
        <div
            className={isChosen ? 'feed-choice chosen' : 'feed-choice'}
            onClick={() => setFeedChoice(type)}
        >
            <img
                src={require(`../../../public/images/${type}${
                    isChosen ? '-fill' : ''
                }.svg`)}
            />
            <span>{type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.slice(1)}</span>
        </div>
    )
}

type Props = {
    feedChoice: QueryType
    setFeedChoice: (query: QueryType) => void
}

const Feed = ({ feedChoice, setFeedChoice }: Props) => {
    const { width } = useWindowDimension()
    const [isDropdown, setDropdown] = useState<boolean>(false)

    const setChoice = (query: QueryType) => {
        setFeedChoice(query)
        setDropdown(false)
    }

    if (width !== null && width <= 600) {
        return (
            <div className="feed-row">
                {isDropdown ? (
                    <div>
                        <FeedChoice
                            type={QueryType.New}
                            isChosen={feedChoice === QueryType.New}
                            setFeedChoice={setChoice}
                        />
                        <FeedChoice
                            type={QueryType.Boost}
                            isChosen={feedChoice === QueryType.Boost}
                            setFeedChoice={setChoice}
                        />
                        <FeedChoice
                            type={QueryType.Comments}
                            isChosen={feedChoice === QueryType.Comments}
                            setFeedChoice={setChoice}
                        />
                        <FeedChoice
                            type={QueryType.Squash}
                            isChosen={feedChoice === QueryType.Squash}
                            setFeedChoice={setChoice}
                        />
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <FeedChoice
                        type={feedChoice}
                        isChosen={true}
                        setFeedChoice={() => setDropdown(true)}
                    />
                )}
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <div className="feed-row">
                <FeedChoice
                    type={QueryType.New}
                    isChosen={feedChoice === QueryType.New}
                    setFeedChoice={setFeedChoice}
                />
                <div className="divider"></div>
                <FeedChoice
                    type={QueryType.Boost}
                    isChosen={feedChoice === QueryType.Boost}
                    setFeedChoice={setFeedChoice}
                />
                <div className="divider"></div>
                <FeedChoice
                    type={QueryType.Comments}
                    isChosen={feedChoice === QueryType.Comments}
                    setFeedChoice={setFeedChoice}
                />
                <div className="divider"></div>
                <FeedChoice
                    type={QueryType.Squash}
                    isChosen={feedChoice === QueryType.Squash}
                    setFeedChoice={setFeedChoice}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Feed
```

Here is my initial test that is only testing if the text properly appears in the DOM, which it does:

```
import React from 'react'
import { screen, render } from '@testing-library/react'
import Feed from '../components/feed/feed'
import useWindowDimensions from '../hooks/useWindowDimensions'

test('should render all of the QueryTypes in the Feed', () => {
    render(<Feed />)
    
    
    expect(screen.getByText(/new/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(screen.getByText(/boost/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(screen.getByText(/comments/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(screen.getByText(/squash/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write tests for each set of props for `Feed`, and one test mocking the `setFeedChoice` props and asserting on its calls :

```js
const setFeedChoiceMock = jest.fn();

test('calls callback correctly', () => {
    render(<Feed feedChoice=... setFeedChoice={setFeedChoiceMock} />)

    // click on whatever makes the drop down open
    userEvent.click(...);

    // click on one option
    userEvent.click(screen.getByText(...));

    // check that the callback was called
    expect(setFeedChoiceMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith("expected parameter, option text...");
});

// write other tests changing the feedChoice props to ensure all cases work well
test('respects feedChoice props', () => {
    render(<Feed feedChoice="other value" setFeedChoice={setFeedChoiceMock} />)
    
    // check that feedChoice is correctly used
    expect(screen.getByText(...)).toBeInTheDocument()
});
```

Therefore you are staging the `Feed` component, and you test how it behaves regarding only inputs (props) and outputs (DOM generated, dropdown opening, texts, callback calls). You don't test internal implementation, only what's in and out.

The difficult part may be to interact correctly with the dropdown and make it open/close correctly. You may have to use `waitFor`, or replace `userEvent` by `fireEvent` (in my experience sometimes `fireEvent` is more reliable - but less realistic). See [React Testing Library: When to use userEvent.click and when to use fireEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64006345/react-testing-library-when-to-use-userevent-click-and-when-to-use-fireevent) on this subject.

Comment: I think more of my confusion comes from how to access the dropdown menu using the userEvent.click()

Comment: For example, I just clicked on the "new" text, and the className in the DOM updates  to "feed-choice chosen" as opposed to only "feed-choice", but now what is best from here? I tried clicking on "new" again, but that did not work.

Comment: Indeed it can be frustrating to interact correctly with UI component, if you could build a sandbox maybe I could have a look

Comment: Here's a sandbox to the entire project - you can find the feed component under components: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-hamilton-v51jmq?file=/src/__tests__/feed.js

Comment: you should setup a working minimal reproducible example (remove all unecessary stuff, stage your component)

Comment: sorry I just do not have time to do that right now ...

Comment: It's okay if you can't look at the code, it is just strange that when I expect the mock to be called with "new", I get an error saying that the function was called 0 times.

Comment: Nevermind, just fixed it. I was calling the setFeedChoiceMock incorrectly.